Bingo Android Application with a strange behavior, soft restarting
I've created a Bingo app, using Kotlin. It currently has an initial Fragment that is black, and a start game button that takes you to the game fragment.
Whenever you hit the 'winner' button it resets the game, and changes the background color for the next game (red to green for example)
It's being reported to me that the app is 'restarting' in the middle of games, going back to Game 1 (Red.)
I've been told that it happens randomly, with, or without input (someone claimed they were on break and when they came back it was restarted)
This doesn't really make any sense to me. I don't understand how the app could have this behavior. I can't replicate the issue with my device and have no idea how to debug the problem.
Has anyone else had any similar experiences with an android app having this behavior?
The device everyone uses is a Chromebook.
I have tried to recreate the issue on my device with no success. I have told all the users to make sure they updated their machines to the latest version of Android.

Probably the app is crashing.  You will need logs to know more.

But if the app was crashing, wouldn't it restart from the very beginning, on the black screen? Why is it restarting to the first game? And why can't I replicate the problem?

I'm not sure of the exact details of how applications are restarted after crashes (and it could depend how your application is written), but it's possible that it's restarting the Activity in a way that preserves some state about the application (such as which Activity was present, etc.).  As for why you can't replicate it, it's possible there is something different about the users' devices than yours.  Alternately, for the case of coming back after a break, it could be a case of your app not saving its state and being killed due to being in the background.
